# How can I create an array from a json object?

Tags: json, lodash

My json looks like this, it consists of objects and a few other properties:

```
let jsonobject =  {
       "one":{ id:'Peter'},
       "two":{ id:'John'},
       "three":{ id:'Ko'},
       "id":1,
       "name":'Jack'
}
```

I want to convert this to an array with lodash or something, the result would be:

```
[{ id:'Peter'},
{ id:'John'},
{ id:'Ko'}]
```

So I can use _.values(jsonobject) but how can I ditch the id and the name property which are obviously no objects? I want a compact solution and/or use lodash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Get all values for the outer object, (2) filter non object items.

```
_.filter(_.values(jsonobject), _.isObject)
```

Or alternatively the chained variant:

```
_(jsonobject).values().filter(_.isObject).value()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) with an [isObject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isObject) predicate to get the values.

```
var result = _.filter(jsonobject, _.isObject);
```

```js
let jsonobject = {
  "one": {
    id: 'Peter'
  },
  "two": {
    id: 'John'
  },
  "three": {
    id: 'Ko'
  },
  "id": 1,
  "name": 'Jack'
};

var result = _.filter(jsonobject, _.isObject);

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the key in your object and store those that are objects in an array.

```js
 var obj = {
       "one":{ id:'Peter'},
       "two":{ id:'John'},
       "three":{ id:'Ko'},
       "id":1,
       "name":'Jack'
};

var arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
        arr.push(obj[key]);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I appreciate it but looking for something more compact.